# Trying to count a grouping and only return greater than 1

Tags: sql, select, nest, having, group

I'm looking to write a SQL statement but having trouble.

Let's say I have a table with the following data:

| id | ip |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 |

I want the results of my query on this table to be:

| id | ip |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 |

As you can see, it omits the 5 3 data because it doesn't have more than one id with the same ip. Is there a nesting that needs to be done?

Sorry, tried:

```
select distinct poster_id, poster_ip from
`phpbbkp_posts` where poster_id in
(select poster_id 
from
(select distinct poster_id, poster_ip from `phpbbkp_posts`) p  
group by poster_id 
having count(*) > 1)
order by poster_id
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, have you even tried anything???  SO is not a free coding service website.  You are expected to do your work.  If it doesn't work, we can help.

Comment: Sorry, new and learning how to post. I have corrected.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "Didn't work."?

Comment: Yes, it gives me the 5 3 part. It will not look at the count statement and associate it with the grouping of the id's being greater than 1 for a single ip.

Comment: Based on your query, I don't see why 5 3 does not appear?  It should appear.

Comment: I don't want it to appear. I was talking about the results I am looking for when I said it omits the 5 3 data.

Comment: Your posted data shows two 5/3 rows, so that *is* a count > 1

Comment: Hi Hans, you're not reading it correctly. There is only 1 id associated with that ip (3 5), multiple times is ok. The others all have 2 id associated with a single ip. Those are the ones I want returned.

Comment: I figured it out! Needed nesting and an in clause.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me just a little inverse logic on what I counted

```
    SELECT poster_id, poster_ip FROM `phpbbkp_posts`
    WHERE  poster_ip 
    IN(
    SELECT   poster_ip 
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT poster_id, poster_ip FROM `phpbbkp_posts`
    ) AS P
    GROUP BY poster_ip
    HAVING COUNT(poster_id) > 1

    )
```